# Finding the Local Maxima in a set of data

Tags: python, sorting, physics

I am working on a Physics lab report, and using a sensor I gathered a massive amount of data on how the angle of a swinging pendulum varies over time. The sample is over 3 minutes, and there are over 3000 data points. When plotted on a graph, it produces a sinusoidal curve, as it should.

The problem occurs when I try to find the maxima using Python. I need the maxima to see the effects of dampening on the pendulum. When I run the following piece of code, I get only 29 maxima, and I know that there are ~150 maxima. How can I improve my code to get all of them?

My algorithm checks 4 points ahead of and behind a reference point, and if the reference point has the greatest value, it is added to an array of maxima.

Please do note that I'm still a beginner at python, so if you use any complicated language it will most likely go over my head, so, sorry for that in advance.

```
angle = allAngles.readlines()

maxima = [0]

def checker(number):
    counter = 0
    for j in range(-4, 5):
        if float(angle[number + j]) <= float(angle[number]):
            counter += 1
    if counter == 9:
        return True

for i in range(4, len(angle)-6):
     if checker(i):
         if float(angle[i]) != maxima[len(maxima)-1]:
            maxima.append(float(angle[i]))
```

angleData.txt contains the following data:

```
0
0
0.0349065850399
0.0698131700798
0.10471975512
0.13962634016
0.191986217719
0.244346095279
0.279252680319
0.331612557879
0.383972435439
0.436332312999
0.488692190558
0.541052068118
0.575958653158
0.610865238198
0.628318530718
0.645771823238
0.663225115758
0.680678408278
0.680678408278
0.698131700798
0.698131700798
0.715584993318
0.733038285838
0.733038285838
0.733038285838
0.733038285838
0.733038285838
0.733038285838
0.733038285838
0.733038285838
0.733038285838
0.733038285838
0.733038285838
0.733038285838
0.733038285838
0.750491578358
0.750491578358
0.750491578358
0.750491578358
0.767944870878
0.767944870878
0.767944870878
0.767944870878
0.785398163397
0.785398163397
0.785398163397
0.785398163397
0.785398163397
0.785398163397
0.785398163397
0.785398163397
0.785398163397
0.785398163397
0.785398163397
0.785398163397
0.785398163397
0.785398163397
0.802851455917
0.802851455917
0.802851455917
0.802851455917
0.802851455917
0.802851455917
0.802851455917
0.802851455917
0.802851455917
0.802851455917
0.767944870878
0.698131700798
0.593411945678
0.453785605519
0.279252680319
0.0872664625997
-0.12217304764
-0.314159265359
-0.506145483078
-0.628318530718
-0.715584993318
-0.785398163397
-0.785398163397
-0.750491578358
-0.663225115758
-0.523598775598
-0.349065850399
-0.157079632679
0.0349065850399
0.244346095279
0.418879020479
0.575958653158
0.698131700798
0.750491578358
0.767944870878
0.733038285838
0.645771823238
0.506145483078
0.349065850399
0.157079632679
-0.0523598775598
-0.261799387799
-0.436332312999
-0.593411945678
-0.715584993318
-0.785398163397
-0.802851455917
-0.767944870878
-0.698131700798
-0.575958653158
-0.418879020479
-0.226892802759
-0.0174532925199
0.174532925199
0.366519142919
0.523598775598
0.645771823238
0.733038285838
0.767944870878
0.750491578358
0.680678408278
0.558505360638
0.401425727959
0.209439510239
0.0174532925199
-0.191986217719
-0.383972435439
-0.541052068118
-0.680678408278
-0.767944870878
-0.802851455917
-0.785398163397
-0.715584993318
-0.610865238198
-0.471238898038
-0.296705972839
-0.0872664625997
0.10471975512
0.314159265359
0.471238898038
0.610865238198
0.698131700798
0.750491578358
0.750491578358
0.698131700798
0.593411945678
0.453785605519
0.279252680319
0.0872664625997
-0.12217304764
-0.314159265359
-0.488692190558
-0.628318530718
-0.733038285838
-0.785398163397
-0.785398163397
-0.750491578358
-0.645771823238
-0.523598775598
-0.349065850399
-0.157079632679
0.0523598775598
0.244346095279
0.418879020479
0.575958653158
0.680678408278
0.733038285838
0.750491578358
0.715584993318
0.628318530718
0.488692190558
0.331612557879
0.13962634016
-0.0523598775598
-0.261799387799
-0.436332312999
-0.593411945678
-0.698131700798
-0.767944870878
-0.785398163397
-0.750491578358
-0.680678408278
-0.558505360638
-0.401425727959
-0.209439510239
-0.0174532925199
0.191986217719
0.366519142919
0.523598775598
0.645771823238
0.715584993318
0.750491578358
0.733038285838
0.645771823238
0.541052068118
0.383972435439
0.191986217719
0
-0.191986217719
-0.383972435439
-0.541052068118
-0.663225115758
-0.750491578358
-0.785398163397
-0.767944870878
-0.698131700798
-0.593411945678
-0.453785605519
-0.261799387799
-0.0698131700798
0.12217304764
0.314159265359
0.471238898038
0.610865238198
0.698131700798
0.733038285838
0.733038285838
0.680678408278
0.575958653158
0.418879020479
0.244346095279
0.0523598775598
-0.13962634016
-0.331612557879
-0.506145483078
-0.628318530718
-0.733038285838
-0.767944870878
-0.767944870878
-0.715584993318
-0.628318530718
-0.488692190558
-0.314159265359
-0.12217304764
0.0698131700798
0.261799387799
0.436332312999
0.575958653158
0.663225115758
0.733038285838
0.733038285838
0.680678408278
0.593411945678
0.471238898038
0.296705972839
0.10471975512
-0.0872664625997
-0.279252680319
-0.453785605519
-0.593411945678
-0.698131700798
-0.767944870878
-0.767944870878
-0.733038285838
-0.645771823238
-0.523598775598
-0.366519142919
-0.174532925199
0.0174532925199
0.209439510239
0.383972435439
0.541052068118
0.645771823238
0.715584993318
0.733038285838
0.698131700798
0.610865238198
0.506145483078
0.331612557879
0.157079632679
-0.0349065850399
-0.226892802759
-0.401425727959
-0.558505360638
-0.680678408278
-0.750491578358
-0.767944870878
-0.750491578358
-0.663225115758
-0.558505360638
-0.401425727959
-0.226892802759
-0.0349065850399
0.157079632679
0.349065850399
0.506145483078
0.610865238198
0.698131700798
0.733038285838
0.698131700798
0.645771823238
0.523598775598
0.383972435439
0.209439510239
0.0174532925199
-0.191986217719
-0.366519142919
-0.523598775598
-0.645771823238
-0.733038285838
-0.767944870878
-0.750491578358
-0.680678408278
-0.593411945678
-0.436332312999
-0.261799387799
-0.0698131700798
0.12217304764
0.296705972839
0.453785605519
0.593411945678
0.680678408278
0.715584993318
0.715584993318
0.645771823238
0.558505360638
0.418879020479
0.244346095279
0.0523598775598
-0.13962634016
-0.331612557879
-0.488692190558
-0.610865238198
-0.715584993318
-0.750491578358
-0.750491578358
-0.698131700798
-0.610865238198
-0.471238898038
-0.314159265359
-0.12217304764
0.0698131700798
0.261799387799
0.418879020479
0.558505360638
0.645771823238
0.698131700798
0.715584993318
0.663225115758
0.575958653158
0.436332312999
0.279252680319
0.10471975512
-0.10471975512
-0.279252680319
-0.453785605519
-0.593411945678
-0.698131700798
-0.750491578358
-0.750491578358
-0.715584993318
-0.628318530718
-0.506145483078
-0.349065850399
-0.157079632679
0.0349065850399
0.226892802759
0.383972435439
0.523598775598
0.628318530718
0.698131700798
0.715584993318
0.680678408278
0.593411945678
0.471238898038
0.314159265359
0.13962634016
-0.0523598775598
-0.244346095279
-0.418879020479
-0.558505360638
-0.663225115758
-0.733038285838
-0.750491578358
-0.715584993318
-0.645771823238
-0.523598775598
-0.366519142919
-0.191986217719
0
0.174532925199
0.349065850399
0.506145483078
0.610865238198
0.680678408278
0.698131700798
0.680678408278
0.610865238198
0.488692190558
0.349065850399
0.174532925199
-0.0174532925199
-0.209439510239
-0.383972435439
-0.523598775598
-0.645771823238
-0.715584993318
-0.750491578358
-0.733038285838
-0.663225115758
-0.558505360638
-0.401425727959
-0.226892802759
-0.0523598775598
0.13962634016
0.314159265359
0.471238898038
0.593411945678
0.663225115758
0.698131700798
0.680678408278
0.628318530718
0.523598775598
0.366519142919
0.209439510239
0.0174532925199
-0.174532925199
-0.349065850399
-0.506145483078
-0.628318530718
-0.698131700798
-0.733038285838
-0.733038285838
-0.663225115758
-0.575958653158
-0.436332312999
-0.261799387799
-0.0872664625997
0.10471975512
0.296705972839
0.436332312999
0.558505360638
0.645771823238
0.698131700798
0.680678408278
0.628318530718
0.541052068118
0.401425727959
0.226892802759
0.0523598775598
-0.13962634016
-0.314159265359
-0.471238898038
-0.593411945678
-0.680678408278
-0.733038285838
-0.733038285838
-0.680678408278
-0.593411945678
-0.453785605519
-0.296705972839
-0.10471975512
0.0698131700798
0.261799387799
0.418879020479
0.541052068118
0.628318530718
0.680678408278
0.680678408278
0.645771823238
0.541052068118
0.418879020479
0.261799387799
0.0872664625997
-0.10471975512
-0.279252680319
-0.453785605519
-0.575958653158
-0.680678408278
-0.715584993318
-0.733038285838
-0.680678408278
-0.593411945678
-0.471238898038
-0.314159265359
-0.13962634016
0.0523598775598
0.226892802759
0.383972435439
0.523598775598
0.610865238198
0.680678408278
0.680678408278
0.645771823238
0.558505360638
0.436332312999
0.279252680319
0.10471975512
-0.0698131700798
-0.261799387799
-0.418879020479
-0.558505360638
-0.663225115758
-0.715584993318
-0.733038285838
-0.698131700798
-0.610865238198
-0.488692190558
-0.331612557879
-0.157079632679
0.0174532925199
0.191986217719
0.366519142919
0.506145483078
0.610865238198
0.663225115758
0.680678408278
0.645771823238
0.575958653158
0.453785605519
0.314159265359
0.13962634016
-0.0523598775598
-0.226892802759
-0.401425727959
-0.541052068118
-0.645771823238
-0.698131700798
-0.715584993318
-0.698131700798
-0.628318530718
-0.506145483078
-0.366519142919
-0.191986217719
0
0.174532925199
0.349065850399
0.488692190558
0.593411945678
0.645771823238
0.680678408278
0.645771823238
0.575958653158
0.471238898038
0.331612557879
0.157079632679
-0.0174532925199
-0.209439510239
-0.366519142919
-0.523598775598
-0.628318530718
-0.698131700798
-0.715584993318
-0.698131700798
-0.628318530718
-0.523598775598
-0.383972435439
-0.209439510239
-0.0349065850399
0.157079632679
0.314159265359
0.471238898038
0.575958653158
0.645771823238
0.663225115758
0.645771823238
0.593411945678
0.488692190558
0.349065850399
0.174532925199
0
-0.191986217719
-0.349065850399
-0.506145483078
-0.610865238198
-0.680678408278
-0.715584993318
-0.698131700798
-0.628318530718
-0.541052068118
-0.401425727959
-0.226892802759
-0.0523598775598
0.12217304764
0.296705972839
0.436332312999
0.558505360638
0.628318530718
0.663225115758
0.645771823238
0.593411945678
0.488692190558
0.349065850399
0.191986217719
0.0174532925199
-0.157079632679
-0.331612557879
-0.488692190558
-0.593411945678
-0.680678408278
-0.715584993318
-0.698131700798
-0.645771823238
-0.541052068118
-0.401425727959
-0.244346095279
-0.0698131700798
0.10471975512
0.279252680319
0.436332312999
0.541052068118
0.628318530718
0.663225115758
0.645771823238
0.593411945678
0.506145483078
0.366519142919
0.209439510239
0.0349065850399
-0.13962634016
-0.314159265359
-0.471238898038
-0.575958653158
-0.663225115758
-0.698131700798
-0.698131700798
-0.645771823238
-0.558505360638
-0.418879020479
-0.261799387799
-0.0872664625997
0.0872664625997
0.261799387799
0.418879020479
0.523598775598
0.610865238198
0.645771823238
0.645771823238
0.593411945678
0.506145483078
0.383972435439
0.226892802759
0.0523598775598
-0.12217304764
-0.296705972839
-0.453785605519
-0.575958653158
-0.663225115758
-0.698131700798
-0.698131700798
-0.645771823238
-0.558505360638
-0.436332312999
-0.279252680319
-0.10471975512
0.0698131700798
0.244346095279
0.401425727959
0.523598775598
0.610865238198
0.645771823238
0.645771823238
0.610865238198
0.523598775598
0.383972435439
0.244346095279
0.0698131700798
-0.10471975512
-0.279252680319
-0.436332312999
-0.558505360638
-0.645771823238
-0.698131700798
-0.698131700798
-0.645771823238
-0.558505360638
-0.436332312999
-0.296705972839
-0.12217304764
0.0523598775598
0.226892802759
0.383972435439
0.506145483078
0.593411945678
0.645771823238
0.645771823238
0.610865238198
0.523598775598
0.401425727959
0.244346095279
0.0872664625997
-0.10471975512
-0.261799387799
-0.418879020479
-0.541052068118
-0.628318530718
-0.680678408278
-0.698131700798
-0.645771823238
-0.575958653158
-0.453785605519
-0.296705972839
-0.12217304764
0.0523598775598
0.209439510239
0.366519142919
0.488692190558
0.593411945678
0.628318530718
0.645771823238
0.610865238198
0.523598775598
0.401425727959
0.261799387799
0.0872664625997
-0.0872664625997
-0.261799387799
-0.401425727959
-0.541052068118
-0.628318530718
-0.680678408278
-0.680678408278
-0.645771823238
-0.575958653158
-0.453785605519
-0.314159265359
-0.13962634016
0.0349065850399
0.209439510239
0.366519142919
0.488692190558
0.575958653158
0.628318530718
0.645771823238
0.610865238198
0.523598775598
0.418879020479
0.261799387799
0.10471975512
-0.0698131700798
-0.244346095279
-0.401425727959
-0.523598775598
-0.628318530718
-0.680678408278
-0.680678408278
-0.645771823238
-0.575958653158
-0.453785605519
-0.314159265359
-0.157079632679
0.0174532925199
0.191986217719
0.349065850399
0.471238898038
0.575958653158
0.628318530718
0.628318530718
0.610865238198
0.523598775598
0.418879020479
0.279252680319
0.10471975512
-0.0698131700798
-0.244346095279
-0.383972435439
-0.523598775598
-0.610865238198
-0.663225115758
-0.680678408278
-0.645771823238
-0.575958653158
-0.453785605519
-0.314159265359
-0.157079632679
0.0174532925199
0.191986217719
0.349065850399
0.471238898038
0.558505360638
0.610865238198
0.628318530718
0.593411945678
0.523598775598
0.418879020479
0.279252680319
0.12217304764
-0.0523598775598
-0.226892802759
-0.383972435439
-0.506145483078
-0.610865238198
-0.663225115758
-0.680678408278
-0.645771823238
-0.575958653158
-0.471238898038
-0.331612557879
-0.157079632679
0.0174532925199
0.174532925199
0.331612557879
0.453785605519
0.558505360638
0.610865238198
0.628318530718
0.593411945678
0.523598775598
0.418879020479
0.279252680319
0.12217304764
-0.0523598775598
-0.226892802759
-0.366519142919
-0.506145483078
-0.593411945678
-0.663225115758
-0.680678408278
-0.645771823238
-0.575958653158
-0.471238898038
-0.331612557879
-0.174532925199
0
0.174532925199
0.331612557879
0.453785605519
0.558505360638
0.610865238198
0.628318530718
0.593411945678
0.523598775598
0.418879020479
0.279252680319
0.12217304764
-0.0523598775598
-0.209439510239
-0.366519142919
-0.506145483078
-0.593411945678
-0.645771823238
-0.663225115758
-0.645771823238
-0.575958653158
-0.471238898038
-0.331612557879
-0.174532925199
0
0.174532925199
0.314159265359
0.453785605519
0.541052068118
0.610865238198
0.628318530718
0.593411945678
0.523598775598
0.418879020479
0.279252680319
0.12217304764
-0.0349065850399
-0.209439510239
-0.366519142919
-0.488692190558
-0.593411945678
-0.645771823238
-0.663225115758
-0.645771823238
-0.575958653158
-0.471238898038
-0.331612557879
-0.174532925199
0
0.157079632679
0.314159265359
0.453785605519
0.541052068118
0.593411945678
0.610865238198
0.593411945678
0.523598775598
0.418879020479
0.279252680319
0.12217304764
-0.0349065850399
-0.209439510239
-0.366519142919
-0.488692190558
-0.593411945678
-0.645771823238
-0.663225115758
-0.628318530718
-0.575958653158
-0.471238898038
-0.331612557879
-0.174532925199
0
0.157079632679
0.314159265359
0.436332312999
0.541052068118
0.593411945678
0.610865238198
0.593411945678
0.523598775598
0.418879020479
0.279252680319
0.12217304764
-0.0349065850399
-0.209439510239
-0.366519142919
-0.488692190558
-0.575958653158
-0.645771823238
-0.663225115758
-0.628318530718
-0.558505360638
-0.453785605519
-0.331612557879
-0.174532925199
0
0.157079632679
0.314159265359
0.436332312999
0.541052068118
0.593411945678
0.610865238198
0.575958653158
0.523598775598
0.418879020479
0.279252680319
0.12217304764
-0.0349065850399
-0.209439510239
-0.366519142919
-0.488692190558
-0.575958653158
-0.645771823238
-0.645771823238
-0.628318530718
-0.558505360638
-0.453785605519
-0.314159265359
-0.174532925199
0
0.157079632679
0.314159265359
0.436332312999
0.541052068118
0.593411945678
0.610865238198
0.575958653158
0.506145483078
0.401425727959
0.279252680319
0.12217304764
-0.0523598775598
-0.209439510239
-0.366519142919
-0.488692190558
-0.575958653158
-0.628318530718
-0.645771823238
-0.628318530718
-0.558505360638
-0.453785605519
-0.314159265359
-0.157079632679
0
0.157079632679
0.314159265359
0.436332312999
0.523598775598
0.593411945678
0.593411945678
0.575958653158
0.506145483078
0.401425727959
0.261799387799
0.12217304764
-0.0523598775598
-0.209439510239
-0.366519142919
-0.488692190558
-0.575958653158
-0.628318530718
-0.645771823238
-0.610865238198
-0.558505360638
-0.453785605519
-0.314159265359
-0.157079632679
0
0.174532925199
0.314159265359
0.436332312999
0.523598775598
0.575958653158
0.593411945678
0.575958653158
0.506145483078
0.401425727959
0.261799387799
0.10471975512
-0.0523598775598
-0.209439510239
-0.366519142919
-0.488692190558
-0.575958653158
-0.628318530718
-0.645771823238
-0.610865238198
-0.541052068118
-0.436332312999
-0.296705972839
-0.157079632679
0.0174532925199
0.174532925199
0.314159265359
0.436332312999
0.523598775598
0.575958653158
0.593411945678
0.558505360638
0.488692190558
0.383972435439
0.261799387799
0.10471975512
-0.0523598775598
-0.226892802759
-0.366519142919
-0.488692190558
-0.575958653158
-0.628318530718
-0.645771823238
-0.610865238198
-0.541052068118
-0.436332312999
-0.296705972839
-0.13962634016
0.0174532925199
0.174532925199
0.314159265359
0.436332312999
0.523598775598
0.575958653158
0.593411945678
0.558505360638
0.488692190558
0.383972435439
0.244346095279
0.10471975512
-0.0698131700798
-0.226892802759
-0.366519142919
-0.488692190558
-0.575958653158
-0.628318530718
-0.628318530718
-0.593411945678
-0.523598775598
-0.418879020479
-0.296705972839
-0.13962634016
0.0174532925199
0.174532925199
0.331612557879
0.436332312999
0.523598775598
0.575958653158
0.593411945678
0.558505360638
0.488692190558
0.366519142919
0.244346095279
0.0872664625997
-0.0698131700798
-0.226892802759
-0.366519142919
-0.488692190558
-0.575958653158
-0.628318530718
-0.628318530718
-0.593411945678
-0.523598775598
-0.418879020479
-0.279252680319
-0.12217304764
0.0349065850399
0.191986217719
0.331612557879
0.453785605519
0.523598775598
0.575958653158
0.575958653158
0.541052068118
0.471238898038
0.366519142919
0.226892802759
0.0698131700798
-0.0872664625997
-0.244346095279
-0.383972435439
-0.488692190558
-0.575958653158
-0.628318530718
-0.628318530718
-0.593411945678
-0.506145483078
-0.401425727959
-0.261799387799
-0.12217304764
0.0523598775598
0.191986217719
0.331612557879
0.453785605519
0.523598775598
0.575958653158
0.575958653158
0.541052068118
0.471238898038
0.349065850399
0.226892802759
0.0698131700798
-0.0872664625997
-0.244346095279
-0.383972435439
-0.488692190558
-0.575958653158
-0.610865238198
-0.628318530718
-0.575958653158
-0.506145483078
-0.401425727959
-0.261799387799
-0.10471975512
0.0523598775598
0.209439510239
0.349065850399
0.453785605519
0.523598775598
0.575958653158
0.575958653158
0.523598775598
0.453785605519
0.349065850399
0.209439510239
0.0523598775598
-0.10471975512
-0.261799387799
-0.383972435439
-0.506145483078
-0.575958653158
-0.610865238198
-0.610865238198
-0.575958653158
-0.488692190558
-0.383972435439
-0.244346095279
-0.0872664625997
0.0698131700798
0.209439510239
0.349065850399
0.453785605519
0.541052068118
0.575958653158
0.558505360638
0.523598775598
0.436332312999
0.331612557879
0.191986217719
0.0349065850399
-0.12217304764
-0.261799387799
-0.401425727959
-0.506145483078
-0.575958653158
-0.610865238198
-0.610865238198
-0.558505360638
-0.488692190558
-0.366519142919
-0.226892802759
-0.0872664625997
0.0698131700798
0.226892802759
0.366519142919
0.471238898038
0.541052068118
0.558505360638
0.558505360638
0.523598775598
0.436332312999
0.314159265359
0.174532925199
0.0349065850399
-0.12217304764
-0.279252680319
-0.401425727959
-0.506145483078
-0.575958653158
-0.610865238198
-0.610865238198
-0.558505360638
-0.471238898038
-0.349065850399
-0.226892802759
-0.0698131700798
0.0872664625997
0.244346095279
0.366519142919
0.471238898038
0.541052068118
0.558505360638
0.558505360638
0.506145483078
0.418879020479
0.296705972839
0.157079632679
0.0174532925199
-0.13962634016
-0.296705972839
-0.418879020479
-0.523598775598
-0.575958653158
-0.610865238198
-0.593411945678
-0.541052068118
-0.453785605519
-0.349065850399
-0.209439510239
-0.0523598775598
0.10471975512
0.244346095279
0.366519142919
0.471238898038
0.541052068118
0.558505360638
0.541052068118
0.488692190558
0.401425727959
0.296705972839
0.157079632679
0
-0.157079632679
-0.296705972839
-0.418879020479
-0.523598775598
-0.575958653158
-0.610865238198
-0.593411945678
-0.541052068118
-0.453785605519
-0.331612557879
-0.191986217719
-0.0349065850399
0.12217304764
0.261799387799
0.383972435439
0.471238898038
0.541052068118
0.558505360638
0.541052068118
```

and more, but I was limited by this post

Comment: You need to debug your code. Find a maxima which is there but not reported, and walk through your code and figure out why this datapoint is not processed properly. Try to limit dataset around this maxima and check if the problem can be reproduced on the smaller dataset.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in your exclusion logic:

```
     if float(angle[i]) != maxima[len(maxima)-1]:
```

Many of your successive maxima have the same value, but are separated by about 25 lines in the file.  Your checking code above specifically excludes these.

If you're trying to keep a "flat-line" maximum from being recorded multiple times, then you need to check against local elements, not the last one that succeeded: check the previous element.

```
     if float(angle[i]) != float(angle[i-1]):
```

There are other things to clean up in the program, but this one will make a needed 
functional difference.

Most notably, remove the continuous conversions: your program deals only with `float`, so covert everything *once*:

```
angle = [float(x) for x in open('qqq').readlines()]
```

Then, use the built-in `max` function, instead of writing your own:

```
 if angle[i] == max(angle[i-4:i+5]):
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! instead of sticking with the `for` loop, I switched over to a `while` loop. Every time a maxima was found, the counter variable would skip ahead 7 units. This helped ensure that none of the data points were repeated, and even if some of the maxima had the same value, they were recognized.

Comment: Great!  Note, however, that this will get a double-max if you have something that sticks there for 14 iterations.  I already see an early one at 13, during the run-up.